# $(document).on('click', selector, function() ) combined with :not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got several list items, when I click on the item I want the browser to redirect to ".title > a" link (href). But I don't want any event on the "notThis" selector.

see the example 
http://jsfiddle.net/VTGwV/29/

```
<div class="item">
<div class="title">
    <a href="www.jsfiddle.net">jsfiddle.net</a>     
</div>
<div> djføljdsaføljdsf a</div>
<div> djføljdsaføljdsf a</div>
<div> djføljdsaføljdsf a</div>
<div class="notThis">
    <a href="/test.html">link1 </a>
    <a href="/test2.html">link2</a>                
</div>
```

​

script

```
​$(document).on('click', '.item', function(event) {
    window.location.href = $(event.currentTarget).find('.title > a').attr('href');        
});​
```

I've tried :not('.notThis') without any luck.

**Changes**
Thanks for all the answers, but I found another problem. If I have a event handler on the whole item , I can't manage to click on the link in "notThis" selector, because it returns only "false". Isn't there a way to use .not / :not combined with $(document).on('click', -------)

Comment: Are you talking about the `return false` in my solution? Just use `return;` then. Of course you can use `:not` with `.on` but it will not help you in your situation.

Comment: As I said, change `return false;` to `return;`: http://jsfiddle.net/VTGwV/30/

Comment: "If I have a event handler on the whole item , I can't manage to click on the link in "notThis" selector" - try my variant, there is no such problem in it. Clicks are captured on wanted elements only.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can test whether the click event originated from within the `.notThis` element (or the element itself):​

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(event) {
    if($(event.target).closest('.notThis').length > 0) {
        return false; // if you want to ignore the click completely
        // return; // else
    }
    window.location.href = $(event.currentTarget).find('.title > a').attr('href');
});​
```

I also think you can use `this` instead of `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: What happens if `event.target` **is** the `<div class="notThis">` element? Will `.closest('.notThis')` still match, and therefore result in a jQuery object with a length property greater than 0?

Comment: @Anthony: Yes. *"Description: Get the first element that matches the selector, **beginning at the current element** and progressing up through the DOM tree."*

Comment: Thanks. I should have really checked the documentation myself before asking.

Comment: Don't think that $(this) can be used. If you click on the div before "notThis" it will not find the "title" . But if I change from find() to closest it will work

Comment: `this` should always refer to `div.item`, since the event handler is set up to handle their click events. This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/VTGwV/28/

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, just use the selector like this:

**Example**

```
$("div.item > div:not(.notThis)").click(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).find('.title > a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax... why do you say that?

Comment: In the original post @plexus81 said he used `:not('.notThis')` and that it did not work for him, this should be used as `:not(.notThis)` **without** the quotes. This is why I said that.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcg49/4/

```
var clickable = $('.item').find('div').not('.notThis');

$(clickable).on('click', function(event) {
    alert($(this).parent().find('.title a').attr('href'));
});
```